# What is considered a good accuracy for trained Word2Vec on an analogy test?

Tags: word2vec

After training Word2Vec, how high should the accuracy be during testing on analogies? What level of accuracy should be expected if it is trained well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analogy test is just a interesting automated way to evaluate models, or compare algorithms.

It might not be the best indicator of how well word-vectors will work for your own project-specific goals. (That is, a model which does *better* on word-analogies might be worse for whatever other info-retrieval, or classification, or other goal you're really pursuing.) So if at all possible, create an automated evaluation that's tuned to your own needs.

Note that the absolute analogy scores can also be quite sensitive to how you trim the vocabulary before training, or how you treat analogy-questions with out-of-vocabulary words, or whether you trim results at the end to just higher-frequency words. Certain choices for each of these may boost the supposed "correctness" of the simple analogy questions, but not improve the overall model for more realistic applications.

So there's no absolute accuracy rate on these simplistic questions that should be the target. Only relative rates are somewhat indicative - helping to show when more data, or tweaked training parameters, seem to improve the vectors. But even vectors with small apparent accuracies on generic analogies might be useful elsewhere.

All that said, you can review a demo notebook like the gensim "Comparison of FastText and Word2Vec" to see what sorts of accuracies on the Google word2vec.c `questions-words.txt' analogy set (40-60%) are achieved under some simple defaults and relatively small training sets (100MB-1GB).